# Basic JQuery Slider - How to remove slide number at bottom?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a Basic JQuery SLider from the following site. http://www.basic-slider.com/
Please give me answer to remove slide number at slider of Basic JQuery Slider..

Comment: Come on man, if you can't even work out basic CSS and debugging with a web-inspector you should not be allowed anywhere near a file-editor or a webserver! JS: `$('.bjqs-markers').hide()` or CSS: `.bjqs-markers{display:none;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could accomplish this in two ways:

**Remove the following lines of code from your html,**

```
<ol class="bjqs-markers h-centered" style="left: 0px;">
  <li class=""><a href="#">1</a></li>
  <li class="active-marker"><a href="#">2</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="#">3</a></li>
</ol>
```

**OR**

**Add the following lines of code to your css.**

```
ol.bjqs-markers {
        display: none;
  }
```

Comment: i cant see this code in html and still i am seeig numbers

Comment: your implementation of slider is probably different.

Answer (score 2):

You could also achieve the desired effect by adding `showmarkers : false` to the js script

```js
<script class="secret-source">
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('#banner-fade').bjqs({
      height      : 320,
      width       : 620,
      responsive  : true,
      showmarkers : false
    });

  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

what about hiding these elements with css:

```
.bjqs-markers {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply hide by adding the following css

```
ol.bjqs-markers {
        display: none;
    }
```